# How can I jump to a specific page in datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to go to a speific page on initComplete:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
    table.page(5).draw(false);
  }
} );
```

But it is not working. My page is still at page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- You need to use `.DataTable` not .`dataTable`
  (specifically for the .page() call, not for the initial init)
- At the time `initComplete` runs, `.DataTable({})` has not returned, so `table` is undefined

This can be confirmed with:

```
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
    console.log(table);
    //table.page(5).draw(false);
  }
```

However, in `initComplete`, you can use `this`, so you don't need the `table` variable.

Changing to `.DataTable` and `this` and your code works fine:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2,
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    $(this).DataTable().page(5).draw(false);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Town</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>
      <td>Nobel House, Regent Centre</td>
      <td>Lothian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Empire</td>
      <td>Milton Keynes Leisure Plaza</td>
      <td>Buckinghamshire</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `table` is not defined in your callback context

The only thing i found in my little research is that you can get the table api from the settings parameter.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34352/passing-datatable-object-to-initcomplete-callback

so maybe it could work like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
    settings.oInstance.api().page(5).draw(false);
  }
});
```

I didnt try though

Comment: Tried it for you and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ke0cjz6L/